# native method in vim to edit multiple lines

Tags: vim

scenario

```
1: some text here okok
2: some more text here
3: end end
4: almost okok
```

when searching `okok`, vim will highlight line `1` and `4`, I want to visual block select line `1` and `4` so I can do `A` or `I` to do editing on line `1` and `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Zach suggested multiple-cursor plugin.  I have checked that plugin some month ago. It looks cool, but I feel `:g/ or :v or :s or macro` can do almost 99% job of that plugin.

E.g. for your requirement, you could just `:g/okok/norm! Ifoobar` or `:g/okok/norm! Afoobar` to do your `I or A` editing. And I think they are very "native" methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select multiple separated lines at once in vanilla vim.

I suggest you use the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin (inspired from Sublime Text). With this plugin, you could put your cursor on `okok` and press `<C-n>` twice to select both occurrences. Then you can make changes to the words.